# Can't figure out how to load yaml document in Dart

Tags: dart, yaml

According to the [readme](https://github.com/dart-lang/yaml) for the Dart-Yaml pub package, I should be able to do the following:

`var db = loadYamlDocument("db.yaml");`

with `print(db['hostname']);` giving me the value I have specified for port in that yaml, however I'm told that YamlDocument has no instance method `[]`.  Okay, I guess that object doesn't have map behaviors, which is something I would have expected it to have.  Looking through the docs, there's mention of a YamlMap, but I don't see how to implement that at all.

If I simply try `print(db);` I actually get the string: `'db.yaml'`.

So I tried using `new File('db.yaml');` and then sending that variable into the `loadYamlDocument` method, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any luck reading a yaml document and getting a map out of it in Dart?

Comment: What does the YAML content look like? https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/master/tool/grind.dart#L102 is an example how to read the package version from `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: My `db.yaml` file is just a yaml of my db connection info.  What ends up coming out of the `loadYaml` and `loadYamlDocument` are just strings, not maps.  As shown in your example, you must read the file as a string in order to pass it to `loadYaml` so the I must be misunderstanding the purpose and functionality of `loadYamlDocument`

Answer (score 8):

```
import "dart:io";
import "package:yaml/yaml.dart";

main() {
  File file = new File('pubspec.yaml');
  String yamlString = file.readAsStringSync();
  Map yaml = loadYaml(yamlString);
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Map loadYamlFileSync(String path) {
  File file = new File(path);
  if (file?.existsSync() == true) {
    return loadYaml(file.readAsStringSync());
  }
  return null;
}

Future<Map> loadYamlFile(String path) async{
  File file = new File(path);
  if ((await file?.exists()) == true) {
    String content = await file.readAsString();
    return loadYaml(content);
  }
  return null;
}

main(List<String> args){
  print(loadYamlFileSync("pubspec.yaml"));
}
```

Comment: This works.  Is there a "more simple" way to do this?  I would assume that `loadYamlDocument` ought to do this for me, and that I wouldn't have to do this abstraction myself, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: From having a quick look at the docs, it seems the shorter version of this would be: `var db = loadYamlDocument('db.yaml').contents.value;`

_PS. I am unable to test this at the moment so I may be wrong._

Comment: The api name `loadYamlDocument` is a bit confusing I know, but it only takes full yaml String. 
Maybe I am wrong, but to be compatible with server And browser, the yaml package can't manipulate `File`, so it is only parsing String.
But the abstraction is pretty simple, I edited my answer with functions that you can copy/paste

Comment: This is great, note that you do not need the null check '?.'

Answer (score 3):

Check the [documentation pages for the Yaml package](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/yaml/2.1.12/yaml/yaml-library.html).

`loadYamlDocument()` returns a `YamlDocument` which is a 'heavyweight' class that gives you access to all the features of a Yaml document.

You probably want to use `loadYaml`, which in most cases is going to return a `Map`. The description says that the actual implementation of the map is a `YamlMap` (the Yaml package's implementation of a `Map`, that they presumably need to use instead of a `HashMap` for some technical reason).

Comment: BTW, sorry to essentially do an 'RTFM' on you, but it didn't seem like you were utilizing the documentation pages, and doing so would help you out.

Comment: No, I totally get that, I should have specified that I actually tried this.  I have to say, I don't think the readme for this package is very well thought-out.  The contents of `loadYaml` being called on `'db.yaml'` just appears to actually be the string, `db.yaml` and not in fact a map.  `loadYaml` appears to be for yaml literal strings.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed that you are parsing a string 'db.yaml' rather than a file named 'db.yaml', in which case you would in fact get a string out of `loadYaml` rather than a map.